# Catch me if you can!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

This thing ran so fast! No one even had a chance to see what it was. As people recovered from the initial shock, a little note with handwriting lay on the ground:

> First you must take a look
>
> Next you can eat or cook
>
> Then half the way around
>
> You'll find me in a book!

Can you find it?

Comment: Oh, no, I think you are talking about the waiter with the huge bill!

Comment: @rhsquared You are right it does bring Gordon Ramsay leaping out of the kitchen with a meat cleaver to mind, but I can assure you that culinary finesse isn't one of this thing's strongest points.

Comment: This is my first ever puzzle. I hope it conforms to expectations.

Comment: @Rubio Answer found. Any feedback on style/tags/formulation welcome.

Comment: I’d say the current tags look good now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmm first answer was wrong, but with help from Nikhil Eshvar things got better.

First you must take a look

> probably C - solved by Nikhil Eshvar (C=see) (old answer ?first letter i (sounds like eye))

Next you can eat or cook

> next letter p ? (sounds like pea - vegetable to eat raw or cook and eat)

Then half the way around

> rotate p by 180 degrees to get d ? or could by half circle.. u? (or U turn!) (old answer ? C is half a circle and it is also rot13(p) (halfway around the alphabet) )

You'll find me in a book!

> CPD or CPU -- maybe CPU in a mac**book**n or note**book** ? ( old answer IPC google search brought up Inidian Penal Code in a book, but that sounds wrong.)

Comment: Well, you are 25% the way there Working out which is right sets the right approach.

Comment: I updated tags to indicate that the answer is a word and that one or two lines can be thought of as wordplay

Comment: A second of your answers is also close.

Comment: @Sentinel , many thanks for the feedback - I was worried it was 0% correct!-- but I am not sure where to go next so.. will have to think about it

Comment: The puzzle is fairly unsophisticated. I think on the whole your approach is correct, you are closer than you think actually

Comment: What about "c" for First you must take a look? (I see = I 'c')

Comment: @NikhilEshvar Doh... you are so correct!!! thanks :-)

Comment: @NikhilEshvar - ok, this may have unlocked the answer...

Comment: @Sentinel - maybe this revised answer is correct - or at least closer after help from Nikhil Eshvar

Comment: @tom You got it! It is the second variant with the letter that represents a type of road turn that is isn't a full circle. And yes, both types of book apply! :-)